# Dreamweaver CS6: Fonts Don't Work

Tags: html, css, fonts, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 for coding and i am making a web site right now.

I've got a problem about fonts. Usually, when i add a font to the Dreamweaver font library and use that font in CSS i can't see that font used on my web site. I mean font doesn't work. Even if that font is a default Adobe Edge Web Font.

Can you guys please help me fix it?

Comment: Did this work: http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/using-custom-web-fonts-in-dreamweaver

Comment: Unfortunately, did not.

Comment: As a programming question, you need to add a lot more details. If this is a question specifically about using the Dreamweaver CS6 application, this is the wrong place to ask and you should be asking questions over on http://superuser.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your question, but I find that Dreamweaver CS6 doesn't recognize the web fonts that I add through the **Web Fonts** box that will become part of the **font family**.

I attach the font's **CSS** sheet and add the font's name onto `font-family` tag, but fonts on the corresponding web page that I'm designing don't change! Very frustrating!

I think this is the answer: CS6 adds the wrong name to the font-family in the **Font Families** text box. So, open that particular font's CSS sheet and copy the name of the font from the line in the font CSS sheet.

For example, `("font-family: 'Special_font_regular';)`. You would, therefore, add "Special_font_regular" (font name) to the tag `font-family`. This is what you would have in your CSS code under your class or id list of tags: font-family: "Special_font_regular".

Now the new font will appear on your web page that you are designing.